# How to activate my eclipse plugin when a specific editors opens

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My plugin needs to listen to changes (selection and content) of xtext based editors provided by another third-party plugin.

**Edit1**

The issue is not how to listen to the specific events in general. 
Instead the issue is how to trigger the listener registration, since there's no code of my plugin executed (lazy loading) unless it is used by the user through a command for instance.

**Edit2**

Using org.eclipse.ui.IStartup extension point the issue is that in IStartup.earlyStartup() PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow(); is returning null. It looks like this is too early in the startup phase to register the listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener2` listener to be told about all parts opening, closing, being activated ....

```java
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

IPartService partService = window.getPartService();

partService.addPartListener(your listener);
```

The

```java
public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef)
```

method of the listener will be called when a part (editor or view) is opened. The `partRef.getId()` method will give you the id of the part.

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point to declare that your plugin needs to be started early. This lets you declare a class implementing `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup` that is called during Eclipse startup.

Note that the startup runs quite early so not everything is set up. Use `Display.asyncExec` to schedule code to run later:

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(runnable);
```

Comment: Thanks but sorry, I wasn't clear enough. Please see my edit for a better explanation of the issue.

Comment: So I presume there's no declarative way to trigger my plugin's activation on activation of other plugins or even editor types?

Comment: No there isn't a way to do that, you will need the part listener (lots of plugins use it).

Comment: PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow() returns null during startup, see Edit2.

Comment: Added note about using `Display.asyncExec` to run code later during the startup

Comment: The active workbench window may be `null` if your plug-in's activator is run before the first workbench window is created. I had the same problem in the past and solved it by scheduling a Job that tracks when the first window is opened and installs the part listener thereafter.

Comment: Display.asyncExec did the job. Thanks!